# Trouble with file save in adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

i have this code in my app:

```
trace("FLACCodec.encodingCompleteHandler(event):", event);
var myfilelol:File = new File("C://test.flac");
var myfilelolstr:FileStream=new FileStream();
myfilelolstr.open(myfilelol, FileMode.WRITE);
myfilelolstr.writeBytes(flacData);
myfilelolstr.close();
```

I want to save bytearray in .flac file.
But i get this in output:

```
typecheck MethodInfo-1060()
outer-scope = [global Object$ flash.events::EventDispatcher$ flash.display::DisplayObject$ flash.display::InteractiveObject$ flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer$ flash.display::Sprite$ flash.display::MovieClip$ talk$ talk talk/stopRecord]
                       [Object~[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()
  0:findpropstrict trace
                       [Object~[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (global~[O])
  3:pushstring "FLACCodec.encodingCompleteHandler(event):"
                       [Object~[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (global~[O] String~[S])
  6:getlocal1
                       [Object~[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (global~[O] String~[S] *[A])
  7:callpropvoid trace 2
                       [Object~[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()
  11:findpropstrict flash.filesystem::File
                       [Object~[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (Object~[A])
  14:pushstring "C://test.flac"
                       [Object~[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (Object~[A] String~[S])
  17:constructprop 1534 1
                       [Object~[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (*[A])
  21:coerce flash.filesystem::File
```

What' wrong? Thank you for your help!
(sorry for my English)

Comment: Who or what is flacData?

Comment: var flacData : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
and then i write recorded sound to it.

Comment: even if i try to make txt, i get this: http://pastebin.com/VNw7c5xx
    var myfilelol:File = new File("C://test.txt");
    var myfilelolstr:FileStream=new FileStream();
    myfilelolstr.open(myfilelol, FileMode.WRITE);
    myfilelolstr.writeUTF("test");
    myfilelolstr.close();